# Would becoming an animagus help keep a maledictus from becoming their animal forever?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, fantastic-beasts, animagi, maledictus

An animagus can turn into an animal at will. There is no such thing as an accidental animagus because of the long process. Becoming a maledictus is strictly through genetics and is a blood curse where one will be permanently changed into an animal. My understanding is that this happens the more you shift into an animal form.

My question is since both are shifting into an animal, would becoming an animagus give a maledictus the chance to live life as a human? I suppose this would be where the maledictus would basically became an animagus. Would there have to be a different process altogether? Or would the maledictus not have to hold the leaf in their mouth for a month to find their "inner animal" since the blood curse of the maledictus did it for them?

Not sure if the finding of the "inner animal" taking place during the leaf part was from a fanfic or not. Looking forward to what you all think

Answer (score 1):

#### It would be impossible for a Maledictus to become an Animagus, since they do not have magic.

It would not be possible for a Maledictus to become an Animagus, since they do not have the ability to use magic. They are classified as Underbeings, which are defined in the screenplay for Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald as beings with magical ancestry but no powers of their own.

> TINA walks past the street performers working in the open, scrutinizing them. A HALF-TROLL performs feats of strength. **A few misshapen and particularly downtrodden humanoids—UNDERBEINGS without powers but of magical ancestry—shuffle around, taking money from the crowd.** Horns hidden beneath hats, unusual eyes beneath hoods; HALF-ELVES and HALF-GOBLINS juggle and tumble. 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Nagini, a Maledictus, is classified as an Underbeing. This in itself indicates that Maledictuses would therefore have no magical powers, since they belong to a broader category which is defined in part by the lack of magical powers.

> “*He whips open the curtains. There stands NAGINI in a snakeskin dress. Men in the crowd whistle and jeer.*
>
> SKENDER
>
> Once trapped in the jungles of Indonesia, she is the carrier of a blood curse. **Such Underbeings are destined, through the course of their lives, to turn permanently into beasts.**” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*</sup></sub>

Additionally, further proof is that Nagini never uses magic, even when she and others are in danger, and if she did indeed have magical abilities it would have been greatly to her advantage to use them. For example, instead of using magic to protect Credence from Kama, she turns into her snake form.

> “*LETA enters the ornate space lined with sleeping statues of dead Lestranges. JACOB stands backed against the wall next to NAGINI in snake form, who is repeatedly lashing out at KAMA, who is trying to get a clean shot at CREDENCE.*
>
> **KAMA**
>
> *(to NAGINI)*
> Move back! Move! Out of the way! If I must kill you as well as Corvus, I shall!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*</sup></sub>

This is something she would only do if she had no other options, since she is of course reluctant to  use her ability to turn into a snake, because she knows that she will eventually be unable to turn back. If she could have used spells in this case, she almost certainly would have done that instead. Therefore, it is reasonable to conclude from the evidence that Maledictuses do not have the ability to wield magic, and thus cannot become Animagi.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

According to official [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/web-how-do-you-become-animagus), these steps are required to become an animagus (one thing to keep in mind is that animagus involves transforming into another species, so maledictus possibly needs to do this in animal form):

> Step 1: Do your homework in Transfiguration and Potions at least. Becoming an Animagus requires a witch or wizard to be skilled in both these areas in order to stand a chance of achieving such a complex transformation.

A maledictus can certainly do that when he/she is in human form and memory can serve the animal form as animal form of a maledictus is intelligent.

> Step 2: Carry a single Mandrake leaf in your mouth for an entire month – from full moon to full moon to be precise. Yes, we’re serious. If you swallow the leaf or remove it from your mouth at any point, you have to start the whole thing again (no-one likes to see that happen). You then have to find a ‘small crystal phial that receives the pure rays of the moon’, put your saliva-filled leaf inside, and add one of your own hairs.

A maledictus can do this in both human and animal form.

> Step 3: Add a silver teaspoon of dew from a place that neither sunlight nor human feet have touched for a full seven days. And if that wasn’t hard enough, you then have to add the chrysalis of a Death’s-head Hawk Moth to the crystal phial as well. Then put ‘this mixture in a quiet, dark place’ and leave it alone until the next electrical storm. And really leave it alone – don’t even look at it. Don’t even think about looking at it.

The rule doesn't say anything about who needs to do it. Maybe, others can help. Or, depending on Maledictus' cursed animal form, he/she himself/herself can do it.

> Step 4: While waiting for the storm, you must place your wand tip over your heart every sunrise and sundown and speak the following incantation: ‘Amato Animo Animato Animagus’. If you keep repeating your incantation, ‘there will come a time when, with the touch of the wand-tip to the chest, a second heartbeat may be sensed.’ Don’t change anything! Keep going. Keep waiting for that storm!

Now, this is a problem. In animal form, a maledictus may not have vocal cords to speak the incantation. Even if this can be done non verbally, it's not necessary that the animal form has chest or heart.

This step is a serious hurdle unless a variation for maledictus exists.

> Step 5: As soon as lightning appears in the sky, go to the place where you’ve hidden your crystal phial. At last! If you’ve done everything right then you will ‘discover a mouthful of blood-red potion inside it.’ Then move somewhere where you aren’t going to alarm anyone or place yourself in physical danger during your transformation. An Animagus transformation party is definitely a bad idea.

This is perfectly doable by a Maledictus even in animal form.

> Step 6: Place your wand-tip against your heart and speak the incantation ‘Amato Animo Animato Animagus’ and drink the potion. You will then feel fiery pain – lucky you – and an intense double heartbeat.

Again, the same *Step 4* issue.

> Step 7: The shape of the creature into which you will shortly transform will appear in your mind. The instructions then warn: ‘You must show no fear/ It is too late now, to escape the change you have willed’. Yikes!

Perfectly doable by a Maledictus even in animal form.

> Step 8: When your transformation is complete you are strongly advised to pick up your wand and hide it somewhere safe, so you can find it post-transformation. To return to human form, visualise your human self as clearly as you can. Don’t worry if you don’t change back immediately, ‘with practice, you will be able to slip in and out of your animal form at will, simply by visualising the creature’. Once you’re an advanced Animagus, you should be able to transform without your wand.

Once you are transformed into a human, this would be piece of cake and you won't want to change back to cursed animal form.

I am not aware of any more information from the canon on this.

BTW, irrespective of this being feasible or not, this is tough. Even experienced normal human wizards try to avoid it. For a maledictus, this ought to be even tougher. Otherwise, the condition wouldn't have been called a curse.